# When does a BigOh notation O(log n) occurs?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

Can you explain what makes an algoritm to be O(log n)?

I would appreciate if you can show it with a simple code.

Thanks

Comment: This is not a duplicate, but rather a “subquestion” of http://stackoverflow.com/q/487258/96656. The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/487278/96656.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`log(n)/log(i)` is the solution to the reccurence relation

```
f(n) =  f(n/i) + c
```

Each time you encouter a function which can be written as a recursive call where the size of the input is divided by a constant at each iteration.Something like

```
function(input, N){
   do some constant work
   return function(input, N/c);
}
```

Then you have a `Theta(logn)` complexity.

Examples :

- When you search in a balanced search tree : take the tree, of size n, if equal to the root return (constant), or search in the left subtree if smaller (size n/2), search in the right subtree (size n/2) if bigger.
- Exponentialtion `a^n`: if n = 1, then return a. Otherwise exponentiate `a^(n/2)` = b ( problem of size n/2), multiply `b` by `b`, and if n even, multiply by a once.

Answer (score 1):

See [Plain English explanation of Big O](https://stackoverflow.com/a/487278/96656). It’s explained there.

> The simplest definition I can give for Big-O notation is this:
>
> **Big-O notation is a relative representation of the complexity of an algorithm.**
>
> There are some important and deliberately chosen words in that
>   sentence:
>
> - **relative:** you can only compare apples to apples.  You can't compare an algorithm to do arithmetic multiplication to an algorithm
>     that sorts a list of integers.  But two algorithms that do arithmetic
>     operations (one multiplication, one addition) will tell you something
>     meaningful;
> - **representation:** Big-O (in its simplest form) reduces the comparison between algorithms to a single variable.  That variable is
>     chosen based on observations or assumptions.  For example, sorting
>     algorithms are typically compared based on comparison operations
>     (comparing two nodes to determine their relative ordering).  This
>     assumes that comparison is expensive.  But what if comparison is cheap
>     but swapping is expensive?  It changes the comparison; and
> - **complexity:** if it takes me one second to sort 10,000 elements how long will it take me to sort one million?  Complexity in this
>     instance is a relative measure to something else.
>
> Come back and reread the above when you've read the rest.
>
> The best example of Big-O I can think of is doing arithmetic.  Take
>   two numbers (123456 and 789012).  The basic arithmetic operations we
>   learnt in school were:
>
> - addition;
> - subtraction;
> - multiplication; and
> - division.
>
> Each of these is an operation or a problem.  A method of solving these
>   is called an **algorithm**.
>
> Addition is the simplest.  You line the numbers up (to the right) and
>   add the digits in a column writing the last number of that addition in
>   the result.  The 'tens' part of that number is carried over to the
>   next column.
>
> Let's assume that the addition of these numbers is the most expensive
>   operation in this algorithm.  It stands to reason that to add these
>   two numbers together we have to add together 6 digits (and possibly
>   carry a 7th).  If we add two 100 digit numbers together we have to do
>   100 additions.  If we add two 10,000 digit numbers we have to do
>   10,000 additions.
>
> See the pattern?  The **complexity** (being the number of operations)
>   is directly proportional to the number of digits *n* in the larger
>   number.  We call this **O(n)** or **linear complexity**.
>
> Subtraction is similar (except you may need to borrow instead of
>   carry).
>
> Multiplication is different.  You line the numbers up, take the first
>   digit in the bottom number and multiply it in turn against each digit
>   in the top number and so on through each digit.  So to multiply our
>   two 6 digit numbers we must do 36 multiplications.  We may need to do
>   as many as 10 or 11 column adds to get the end result too.
>
> If we have two 100-digit numbers we need to do 10,000 multiplications
>   and 200 adds.  For two one million digit numbers we need to do one
>   trillion (10<sup>12</sup>) multiplications and two million adds.
>
> As the algorithm scales with n-*squared*, this is **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**
>   or **quadratic complexity**.  This is a good time to introduce another
>   important concept:
>
> **We only care about the most significant portion of complexity.**
>
> The astute may have realized that we could express the number of
>   operations as: n<sup>2</sup> + 2n.  But as you saw from our example
>   with two numbers of a million digits apiece, the second term (2n)
>   becomes insignificant (accounting for 0.00002% of the total operations
>   by that stage).
>
> **The Telephone Book**
>
> The next best example I can think of is the telephone book, normally
>   called the White Pages or similar but it'll vary from country to
>   country.  But I'm talking about the one that lists people by surname
>   and then initials or first name, possibly address and then telephone
>   numbers.
>
> Now if you were instructing a computer to look up the phone number for
>   "John Smith", what would you do?  Ignoring the fact that you could
>   guess how far in the S's started (let's assume you can't), what would
>   you do?
>
> A typical implementation might be to open up to the middle, take the
>   500,000<sup>th</sup> and compare it to "Smith".  If it happens to be
>   "Smith, John", we just got real lucky.  Far more likely is that "John
>   Smith" will be before or after that name.  If it's after we then
>   divide the last half of the phone book in half and repeat.  If it's
>   before then we divide the first half of the phone book in half and
>   repeat.  And so on.
>
> This is called a **bisection search** and is used every day in
>   programming whether you realize it or not.
>
> So if you want to find a name in a phone book of a million names you
>   can actually find any name by doing this at most 21 or so times (I
>   might be off by 1).  In comparing search algorithms we decide that
>   this comparison is our 'n'.
>
> For a phone book of 3 names it takes 2 comparisons (at most).
>  For
>   7 it takes at most 3.
>  For 15 it takes 4.
>  ...
>  For
>   1,000,000 it takes 21 or so.
>
> That is staggeringly good isn't it?
>
> In Big-O terms this is **O(log n)** or **logarithmic complexity**. 
>   Now the logarithm in question could be ln (base e), log<sub>10</sub>,
>   log<sub>2</sub> or some other base.  It doesn't matter it's still
>   O(log n) just like O(2n<sup>2</sup>) and O(100n<sup>2</sup>) are still
>   both O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) gives some examples of orders of common functions:

> O(log(n)), Finding an item in a sorted array with a binary search or a balanced search tree as well as all operations in a Binomial heap.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple example: **binary search**

**Principle**: In every step prunning half of the possible search space (searched array), after at most log(n) steps the algorithm must terminate (because of the cutting in half).